# Issues when searching between dates Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

The query below does not return any values.

```
SELECT o.ea_guid as CLASSGUID, o.Object_Type as CLASSTYPE, 
       o.Name, type.Property, type.Value
FROM ((t_object as o
       INNER JOIN t_objectproperties as location
         ON o.Object_ID = location.Object_ID)
       INNER JOIN t_objectproperties as type 
         ON o.Object_ID = type.Object_ID)
WHERE location.Property = 'Location' 
  AND location.Value = 'ND'
  AND type.Property = 'FDate'
  AND CDate(type.Value) >= CDate('21/02/2014') 
  AND CDate(type.Value) <= CDate('24/02/2014')
```

However if i do the following it returns a set of results that don't fall between the required ranges

```
SELECT o.ea_guid as CLASSGUID, o.Object_Type as CLASSTYPE, 
     o.Name, type.Property, type.Value
  FROM ((t_object as o
         INNER JOIN t_objectproperties as location
           ON o.Object_ID = location.Object_ID)
         INNER JOIN t_objectproperties as type 
           ON o.Object_ID = type.Object_ID)
  WHERE location.Property = 'Location' 
    AND location.Value = 'ND'
    AND type.Property = 'FDate'
    AND type.Value >= CDate('21/02/2014') 
    AND type.Value <= CDate('24/02/2014')
```

I also attempted using `BETWEEN` and it returns results outside of the range.

```
SELECT o.ea_guid as CLASSGUID, o.Object_Type as CLASSTYPE, 
       o.Name, type.Property, type.Value
    FROM ((t_object as o
           INNER JOIN t_objectproperties as location
             ON o.Object_ID = location.Object_ID)
           INNER JOIN t_objectproperties as type 
             ON o.Object_ID = type.Object_ID)
    WHERE location.Property = 'Location' 
      AND location.Value = 'ND'
      AND type.Property = 'FDate'
      AND type.Value BETWEEN CDate('21/02/2014') 
      AND <= CDate('24/02/2014')
```

Comment: Did you try running it without the date parameters in the `WHERE` clause, and it worked?

Comment: @Newbie -Yes but it returns the entire result set as opposed to limiting them to those that fall between those dates.

Comment: I don't think I would use CDate.. I would use `Format(YourDate, "ShortDate")`

Comment: @Newbie: `Format` does the opposite of `CDate`. `Format` converts to string while `CDate` converts to date.

Comment: Okay - converting the field to the `yyyyMMdd` format can work like an integer. 20140401 > 20140331 holds true.

Comment: What kind of data type is `type.Value`?

Comment: @Newbie - It is a string.

Comment: So you're trying to compare a string to a date without converting the string to a date to compare to a date. `type.Value` must be converted to a date. You also need to be aware of how type.Value is formatted when you're converting it using `CDate()`.

Comment: You can check the property sheet and see what kind of field formats are defined.

Comment: @Newbie - I tried that as well and it results in the same output. See my first query. It returns no result.

Comment: @Newbie - What do you mean by property sheet?

Comment: At the top of Access, in the Design tab, top right, there is Property Sheet. You can left click on a field in your query and it will tell you the Format of that field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I tried this, and it worked. You can convert `type.Value` to a Date and then `Format()` it to a Short Date, and pass your parameters as such. No need to mess with a date format that Access doesn't really care for. Just format it.

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.dateString
FROM Table1 AS t1
WHERE Format(CDate(t1.dateString), "Short Date") < Format(#03/31/2014#, "Short Date");
```

`dateString` is a Text field (like you said yours was) and the values I tested with are:

```
+-------------+
|  10/01/2014 |
+-------------+
|  20/02/2014 |
+-------------+
|  31/03/2014 |
+-------------+
```

Here's the SQL for using `BETWEEN`:

```
   SELECT t1.ID, t1.dateString
FROM Table1 AS t1
WHERE Format(CDate(t1.dateString), "Short Date")
 Between
               Format(#03/30/2014#, "Short Date")
 AND  
               Format(#01/01/2014#, "Short Date")
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work if i limit it to a single date e.g. < 03/31/2014. As soon as i try between 2 dates,it returns results out of those date ranges.

Comment: Hm. Did you try to reverse the logic? If it's giving you the opposite (I don't know why it would be) you can just flip the `<` or `>` around?

Comment: I just tried it, and it worked (without reversing the logic). I'll edit my post.

Comment: Am doing exactly what you suggested and it still returns results outside of the range.

Comment: My only guess then is that while type.Value is being converted to a date, it is not being converted properly. Perhaps write a query that converts the type.Value to a Short Date and see what kind of results you get. This will help trouble shoot.

Comment: Look at this [YouTube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TF7RtBGBD98) regarding converting DD/MM/YYYY to MM/DD/YYYY. I'm not familiar with Access liking DD/MM/YYYY format.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with date strings is that dates like `01/02/2014` can be interpreted as `dd/MM/yyyy` or `MM/dd/yyyy`. Better store the dates in reverse format: `yyyy/MM/dd`. I have never seen a format like `yyyy/dd/MM`. Therefore it should be safe with respect to day and month confusion.

An additional advantage of the reverse format is that its string representation compares the same way as its date representation. I.e. sorting strings in `yyyy/MM/dd` format yields a correct order. Therefore it is not necessary to convert them to dates for the comparison.

---

Try to select `Month(CDate(type.Value))` and see if this really always returns months or whether it sometimes returns days. If days are returned, you could try to convert the properties like this

```
DateSerial(Mid$(type.Value, 7)  , Mid$(type.Value, 4, 2), Mid$(type.Value, 1, 2))
```

Comment: `Format (#17/04/2004#, "yyyy/mm/dd")` would be OP's best bet I think? What are your thoughts? Unless he was consistently formatting as Short Date each time also. I use yyyyMMdd also.

Comment: The problem with `yyyyMMdd` is that `CDate` does not recognize it.

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes - Thanks unfortunately i have no control over the way the dates are stored as it is using a third-party application.

Comment: He wouldn't need CDate. If he uses `Format(type.Value, "yyyy/mm/dd")` there is no need for it.

Comment: @Newbie- I tried `Format` however it either returns no results with `Format (#17/04/2004#, "yyyy/mm/dd")` or it returns results outside the range `Format (#17/04/2004#, "dd/mm/yyyy")`

Comment: Are you replacing your dates in lieu of #17/04/2004# ?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Try to select `Month(CDate(type.Value))` and you will se whether the dates are interpreted correctly or whether the days are mistakten as months.

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes - No results are returned

Comment: Does this really return nothing? `SELECT [Value], Month(CDate([Value])) FROM t_objectproperties WHERE [Property] = 'FDate'`. What does the `Value` column really contain? Show some examples.

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes  - Yes. No results are returned. The table holds the values 21/10/2013, 01/01/2014, etc

Comment: Maybe because there is no property `'FDate'`? This is the only condition in this SELECT statement.

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes - There is.

Comment: The SELECT statement shown in my comment MUST return records if there is a property named "FDate"!